# .NET MAUI custom control property not got attached

Tags: c#, .net, validation, maui

I am playing with .Net Maui, and I am trying to figure out how to write an easy validation for component. For example, I created a wrapper named ValidatonFor, where I expect to receive a name of the model field that I want to validate, but I got stuck in the first step.

My custom wrapper component not receives the value set for the bindable properties (FieldName and ShowValidationError).

Here is my component (this is the very beginning of my playing):

```
public partial class ValidationFor : ContentView
{
    public event EventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public static readonly BindableProperty FieldNameProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(FieldName), typeof(string), typeof(ValidationFor));
    public static readonly BindableProperty ShowValidationErrorProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(ShowValidationError), typeof(bool), typeof(ValidationFor));
    
    public string FieldName
    {
        get => (string)GetValue(FieldNameProperty);
        set => SetValue(FieldNameProperty, value);
    }

    public bool ShowValidationError
    {
        get => (bool)GetValue(ShowValidationErrorProperty);
        set => SetValue(ShowValidationErrorProperty, value);
    }

    private string ErrorMessage = string.Empty;
    private Visibility IsValid = Visibility.Hidden;
    private object chiledElement;

    public ValidationFor()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        chiledElement = this.GetTemplateChild(this.FieldName);
        
        if(chiledElement is not null)
            (chiledElement as INotifyPropertyChanged).PropertyChanged += ValueChanged;
    }

    public void ValueChanged(object model, PropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        if (args.PropertyName == FieldName.Split('.').Last()) { Validate(chiledElement); }
    }

    private void Validate(object chiledElement)
    {
        dynamic value = chiledElement.GetType().GetProperty(FieldName.Split('.').Last()).GetValue(chiledElement);
        var  results = new List<ValidationResult>();

        ValidationContext context = new ValidationContext(chiledElement) { MemberName = FieldName.Split('.').Last() };
        Validator.TryValidateProperty(value, context, results);

        if (results.Any())
        {
            if (!ShowValidationError)
            {
                this.ErrorMessage = results.First().ErrorMessage;
                this.IsValid = Visibility.Visible;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            this.ErrorMessage = null;
            this.IsValid = Visibility.Hidden;
        }

        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, null);
    }
}
```

In my test application I am using it like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:validation="clr-namespace:ValidationLibrary;assembly=ValidationLibrary"
             xmlns:viewModel="clr-namespace:Validation.TestApp"
             x:Class="Validation.TestApp.MainPage"
             x:DataType="viewModel:TestViewModel">

    <VerticalStackLayout VerticalOptions="Start">
        <Frame BorderColor="Black">
            <validation:ValidationFor FieldName="Name" ShowValidationError="False">
                <Entry x:Name="Name" Text="{Binding Name, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceEventName=PropertyChanged}" />
            </validation:ValidationFor>
        </Frame>
    </VerticalStackLayout>
    
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: Why do you think the FieldName value not received? The value has been changed though the setter method not fire. If you want to monitor the change, you could use [property-changed callback method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/bindable-properties?view=net-maui-8.0#detect-property-changes)

Answer (score 0):

You need to write A static validation callback method which can be registered with a bindable property by specifying the validateValue parameter for the BindableProperty.Create method.

First, you need to write the BindableProperty method with the `validateValue` parameter.

```
public static readonly BindableProperty AngleProperty = BindableProperty.Create("Angle", typeof(double), typeof(MainPage), 0.0, validateValue: IsValidValue);
```

Then, you need to create a `IsValidValue` method:

```
static bool IsValidValue(BindableObject view, object value)
{
    //logic here
}
```